# Narrow down type of the returned function's parameter of a high order function

Tags: typescript

I think the title can't really convey what I'm trying to do here. But here we go anyway.

I have a function which will return a another function. The thing is which type of function being return will depend on the parameter I put in the first function. Something look like this

```
Function('function2')('what-ever-parameter-of-function2')
Function('function3')('what-ever-parameter-of-function3')
```

What I want to do is that when i hit on the first **()**, it will give autocomplete of either **'function2'** or **'function3'** and base on that, when i hit the 2nd **()** it will give autocomplete on the parameter of the exact function had been choose on the first **()**.

My case is actually much more complex than that, but the concept is basically that.

[This is what I'm trying out.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQLIFdwENwEsD2A7AzqALygDeAUCKFVQGJI4DGmuAjABTSoBOqAtgFyg84LhhwBzAJSCAblgwATANwUw1UHUbMcAJg7c%20g4aInShIseJWV1mpthwBmfTwGgcSXgCNYXM3MVrNWo7bQAWF0N3Tx8-IwsJINAAXzJVUDFwXwAzVAZ4AGEsXl4McFJ0qgAeAGlQWAAPLJwFAgBrWEgsbMQUdAc8ABpQAAV6ptgWghGDXlgsrjwq5DRtPABtGoBdAD51ll22SuoOyEEaweOqTkgAGyxUBUER47MAJXmkLhwAFRhYZZ9NabXZJVLpKBwUA-WDCH5ECo2UAMYqlcBsHB8WCCADk0C4WDgXCgLBxoAAPniCUSoDocWYiiUymC0pD4Ct%20rgCMRyFQqYTfCScYJeSF6PZWJE3MZLP55MoyLZxdo9JxXPETFINZYVFRkpc%20fiBcTIHSRYqxVoHM41VEPN5fHLAhbaMqHBFbW57bEzDLEhbUuDMjk8oVUWVluNmq1QKdur1VgMdhVqnVGtH2p14xzgQgtsMxunJjGZq55r4ljmBus8yC9gcdkd1KdzgbqDd7o9nhb3p9vn84IDE1ya1s6ypwWzobDwPCeRaUUz0Zi5rijTTIKSKfyN3SGeHwFU2fGV7AdhO0ij8OUssIAPKCGFwhGixdowTZN24DFYyQp6hcH2OCgGwFyjH%20hDJjiAQKDiuopGQyRAA)
In this example, i'm trying to have property1 or property2 in the first (), and base on that (function1 and function2) or (function3 and function4) in the 2nd ()

The code that have been comment out is only experiment, I have able to make it autocomplete on either property1 or property2 but no restrain of autocomplete  in the 2nd ()

You will see some error show in the playground, ignore the last one, I just to lazy to write an actual implement of the function. I have 2 question.

1. In the first 2 error, it show

> Type 'Mutations[M][string] | Mutations[M][number] |
> Mutations[M][symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) =>
> any'

I just don't understand why typescript see K as `string | number | symbol`

2. In this code

> ```
> const testO: TestT = {
>       commit: function(name) {
>         return (K, P) => 'void';
>       }
>     }
> ```

If you hover over **K** you will see it had `never` type. I can kinda understand that because there are no common function inside 'property1' and 'property2'. But it just doesn't make sense to me. What I want is just that in the `commit(name: 'property1' |'property2')`' function, when i type in the `name` parameter, it pass that `name` into the next function which will decide what set function to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution wasn't that far off.

You can use a couple of helper extractors to get everything properly lined up, something like

```js
type ExtractParams<T> = T extends (a: infer K) => any ? K : never
type ExtractReturn<T> = T extends (a: any) => infer K ? K :  never
```

Now, your `Commit` and `TestT` types become

```js
type Mutations = {
  'property1': {
    f: (param: string) => void;
    g: (param: string) => string;
  },
  'property2': {
    h: (param: number) => void;
    j: (param: number) => string;
  }
}

type Commit<M extends keyof Mutations> =
  <K extends keyof Mutations[M], P extends Mutations[M][K]>(
    key: K,
    payload: ExtractParams<P> 
  ) => ExtractReturn<P>


type TestT = {
  commit: <K extends keyof Mutations>(
    name: K
  ) => Commit<K>
}
```

and everything works just fine

```js
const a = test.commit('property1')(
  "f", "hello" // OK
) // void

const b = test.commit('property2')(
  "h", 1 // OK
) // void

const c = test.commit('property2')(
  "j", 1 // OK
) // string
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrsAhsAlgewHYGcoF4oDeAUFFAORgBOakloAjGQFyEmlQBmLAFGIpYgC2LLMEooMAcwCUeAHxQAbmhQATANxtSknnwHCoo8VNm4FRiZM2kAvgBo2FarVAAmZq3ZQAFrv5CWDDhBACMISlMFZTVrdgArP31A4LCI+UMxS1ibIhyiUEgoAFEADzFEAGNgAAV-QSwAHgAVBXwmqAgyiAxVHG5EFgkOcKgAaUioRAwQKAB+MahAiEVw-PBoUvKqgCUIYDhKDGbWqHbO4G7eqH6WKZAJoZHRuYWWKAxl1bXCgGE0QUEKGADRgHS6PRwAGsICA0BxYAhkOhsK02A1nudLlCYXCEUhUJgsABtGAAXTsUGqYIuELxSMJJNJRNGpLk3C0UGhIBYowcXj4IAANmhEKoWJsBFVavpGtUFGwJhLKsBdvtDg05URvtAmhBRO18MRSBV-oDgCx0dSsZycfD4PjkVg2RyMEIIDyFek-gCgei5LktURVBAKoL+NATdhgFALqIWLr9VrI6JJngY3rgAA6E0+4DcJw0cIMMjSdmkABEHHLFPL3ggguF5agAHpm1AAPKjIiyVtKFSqJOE6MhNOxrM5s35qiFuggdylti16tQegttud7trvtqQdRqAVUcZ7OmoFT5xFuclstQctxZer3sbnttixSIA)

Comment: Beautiful, i gonna mark this as the correct answer. Only 1 note though, if i add the 2nd parameter to the child function like this (because i actually want to 2nd parameter):
f: (param: string, testparam: boolean) => void;
Then ExtractParams will return never, to tweak around this, i go with 
type ExtractParams<T> = T extends (b: any, a: infer K) => any ? K : never